# reshape data into multiple columns using pivot_longer

Tags: r, reshape

I am using `pivot_longer` to reshape my data from wide to long format into multiple value columns. I know there are related questions ([Pivot_longer 6 columns to 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954418/pivot-longer-6-columns-to-3-columns) or [Tidy dataset with pivot_longer: Multiple columns into two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138600/tidy-dataset-with-pivot-longer-multiple-columns-into-two-columns)), but I could not find a solution so far, probably because my two columns will be of different class, the first one being `POSIXct` and the second one is `numeric`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
    structure(list(compid = c("AT9130162999", "AT9090003478", "AT9070005375", 
"AT9130048156"), iso2c = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), nace4 = c("7010", 
"4211", "2452", "7010"), lastyear = c("2018", "2019", "2019", 
"2019"), `Closing date
                          Last avail. yr` = structure(c(1546214400, 
1577750400, 1585612800, 1577750400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 1` = structure(c(1514678400, 
1546214400, 1553990400, 1546214400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 2` = structure(c(NA, 
1514678400, 1522454400, 1514678400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 3` = structure(c(NA, 
1483142400, 1490918400, 1483142400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 4` = structure(c(NA, 
1451520000, 1459382400, 1451520000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 5` = structure(c(NA, 
1419984000, 1427760000, 1419984000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 6` = structure(c(NA, 
1388448000, 1396224000, 1388448000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 7` = structure(c(NA, 
1356912000, 1364688000, 1356912000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 8` = structure(c(NA, 
1325289600, 1333152000, 1325289600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Closing date
                          Year - 9` = structure(c(NA, 
1293753600, 1301529600, 1293753600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), operatinginc_last = c(NA, 482813, -94300, NA), operatinginc_year1 = c(NA, 
423482, 780400, NA), operatinginc_year2 = c(NA, 404694, 1210300, 
NA), ebit_last = c(1060000, 482813, -94300, 351292), ebit_year1 = c(1501000, 
423482, 780400, 331415), ebit_year2 = c(NA, 404694, 1210300, 
305492), operatingrev_last = c(28463000, 15842418, 13009700, 
11742884), operatingrev_year1 = c(NA, 13734462, 13146300, 10682889
), operatingrev_year2 = c(NA, 13734462, 13146300, 10682889)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
df_l <- df %>%  
pivot_longer(., cols = -(starts_with(c("compid","iso2c","nace4","lastyear","Closing"))), 
               values_to = "value", values_drop_na=T, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("variable","year"))
```

But now I would also like to reshape all the columns that start with `Closing`. How do I do (preferably in one step with `pivot_longer`)?

The expected output should then include a `variable`, `year` and `value` column, but also a `closingdate` and `date` column:

```
 compid    iso2c   nace4   lastyear   `closingdate             ~ `date              ~`variable      ~`year       ~ `value
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 AT913~ AT    7010  2018    `Closing date Last avail. yr` 2018-12-31 ebit  last            28463000                 
 2 AT913~ AT    7010  2018    `Closing date Year - 1`       2017-12-31 ebit  year1           15362687  
 2 AT913~ AT    7010  2018    `Closing date Year - 1`       2016-12-31 ebit  year2           404694
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how you would do that in one call to pivot_longer, because you have different variables with different schemes. And you ALSO want to pivot to longer the closing date variable. So here it is in two calls with some cleaning of the closing variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_l <-   pivot_longer(df, cols = starts_with("Closing"), 
                       values_to = "date", values_drop_na=T,  names_to = c("closing")) %>%
  pivot_longer(., cols = contains("_"), 
               values_to = "value", values_drop_na=T, names_sep = '_', names_to = c("variable",'year')) %>%
  mutate(closing = str_remove_all(closing,'Closing date') %>% 
           str_remove_all(.,'[:cntrl:]') %>%
           str_squish() %>%
           str_trim())
```